# My image isn't display in my html page for some reason?

Tags: html

My image isn't display on my html page but I feel like have inserted everything correctly.

[image]

Comment: It's src as compared to scr

Answer (score 1):

In line number **10** you have written `<img scr ="Image/askLogo.png">`

Instead of that, write `<img src="Image/askLogo.png">`

> **src** instead of **scr**

src is "source"

Comment: And next time please provide the code instead of screenshots. Thanks.